# Issue with html and javascript (smooth scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried adding smooth scrolling to my website. After copying the javascript and jquery from this website: http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/ I added the tags for the smooth scrolling. The smooth scrolling works for everything except one button on the nav bar. This is the code:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="brand"><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">hbvhaf</a></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#welcome" class="smoothScroll"><span>about</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#hotelinfo" class="smoothScroll"><span>bvdsvudva</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#dining" class="smoothScroll"><span>contact</span></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div><!-- navbar -->
</nav>
```

The one button that doesn't smooth scroll is the one that has a div class of "brand". The div is used to specifically style that button in css. Any ideas.

Comment: I think it's because your JS code is targeting 'li' elements. The "Brand", is within a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is a bit of a hack, but why don't you just add this to the top of the page:

```
<div name="top"></div>
```

And then change your code to:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="brand"><a href="#top" class="smoothScroll">hbvhaf</a></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#welcome" class="smoothScroll"><span>about</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#hotelinfo" class="smoothScroll"><span>bvdsvudva</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#dining" class="smoothScroll"><span>contact</span></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div><!-- navbar -->
</nav>
```

Edit for author, example of it working properly:

```
<div name="top">I am the top of the page.</div>
<a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Go To Contact Form</a>

<div style="height:200%"></div>

<div name="contact">contact</div>
<a href="#top" class="smoothScroll">Back to top</a>

<div style="height:200%"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="smoothscroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, I should put all the code in between the div tag of "top"?

Comment: No, I meant add the div tag at the top of the webpage.  Like right after <body>.

Comment: I did that although the smooth scrolling only scrolls back up, not down. Do you have any other tips?

Comment: The reason why I am confused is, I wrote mini version for myself (now added to my post) that works fine.

Comment: I am as confused as you are. When I press the button I made to go down, it pauses for a second and then it just jumps to #top without smooth scrolling. Could I change the js to include the button with the div. Do you have any other ideas. Anything is much appreciated. edit: I got it to work. My issue was that I forgot to add the smooth scroll tag to the button that linked to #top. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Could you post the whole source somewhere like pastebin or something and then share that link with me?  I'm having a hard time thinking of an obvious problem.

Comment: Hey, cool, what worked?  Could you by chance mark it as the answer or up vote it?

Comment: I'll upvote your answer once I get 15 minutes of reputation. My issue was that I forgot to add the smooth scroll class to the button that was programmed to smooth scroll down. Again, thanks a ton and will definitely upvote once I am able to.

Comment: I just added your answer as correct. Thanks a million